# embed C in python

Tags: python, c

I need to find some way to embed a C library and C code in python. I have looked all over and found a lot of embedding python in C examples but not very many visa versa. And I need to make sure I'm embedding the C, and not just re-wrapping it.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "embedding" vs. "rewrapping"?

Comment: Embedding C in python is done by writing python modules in C. I guess you don't like this way -- why?

Comment: I believe you are looking for: http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html

Answer (score 7):

Extending Python with C is straightforward, but not brief. There is an official tutorial titled *Extending Python with C or C++* available [here](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "re-wrapping," but extending with modules is how you use C in Python.

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers!  These may expire, and then your answer will be useless.

Comment: @InkBlend I rephrased the answer to include the title of the tutorial, to make finding it easier if the link breaks. I'm not going to rephrase or copy significant portions of the article here, however. I believe that would be superfluous and possibly plagaristic.